# Aircrack-ng does not have cuda implementation. Are there alternatives?

Tags: wifi, aircrack-ng

I need a program to crack .cap files , and would like to use my cuda devices.
I know there is pyrit, but I have very severe driver issues on Linux with it and it does not exist for windows, and aircrack-ng , a program which is so widely supported and used by a giant community has no support for cuda computing.

Are there any alternatives besides aircrack-ng and pyrit ?

Comment: Edited to bring this back on topic. Asking "why" a particular application has or doesn't have a specific function is rarely answerable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lester T. says, `hashcat` is a good option.

As an add-on, you might also look into GNU `Parallel` in order to use multiple machines as a cluster. Or perhaps `OpenSSI` which uses a single system image scheme to utilize multiple machines with a single operating system. With such a system, aircrack-ng can be made to run the same command on multiple machines using many different wordlists or possibly piping a permutation output into aircrack-ng on each machine.

(edit)

Another method I didn't think of at the time of writing this answer would be software called `openmpi` which is capable of doing the same as the above methods (using multiple machine resources). You can also use `openmpi` to control how many CPU cores and/or hardware threads a process is allowed to use. `openmpi` doesn't require root to use on local machines unless the command or program being executed requires root permissions. You can also setup `openmpi` to autossh to other machines over a network using password-less ssh connections to `node0,node1,node2,...`. It is really quite useful if a high end GPU isn't available for heavy number crunching.

Answer (score 4):

Theres a fork of aircrack using cuda.

Check it out [here](https://github.com/Jubei-Mitsuyoshi/aaa-aircrack-ng-cuda/tree/master/aircrack-ng-cuda)

Alternatively the following listed supports CUDA password cracking too.

1. [John the ripper](https://github.com/piyushcse29/john-the-ripper/blob/master/doc/README-CUDA)
2. [hashcat](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat)

You may want to consider the other specific cracking tool if you are using rainbow tables instead of dictionaries.

1. [Rainbowcrack](http://project-rainbowcrack.com)
2. [Cryptohaze](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptohaze/files/Cryptohaze-Combined/)